# Define custom symbol for custom build configurations in QNX Momentics

Tags: c++, preprocessor, qnx, momentics

Let's make an example in Eclipse: I have two different source files for a Startup with a main-function, but depending on which build configuration I use, either one of them is used, or the other one.

I do this, by defining a custom symbol with the "-d" option in one of the build configurations, and leaving it out in the other one.

```
#ifdef CUSTOMSYMBOL
...
```

Specifically, under Eclipse, I can edit these settings under Project -> Properties -> C/C++ Build -> Settings -> Cygwin C++ Compiler -> Prepocessor
[image: imgdesc]
(I am using Cygwin under Windows for my C++ projects)

This works. Depending on which build configuration I use, only one of the two source files will be built by the compiler and the other one will be ignored.

However, this setting is specific to Cygwin.

I can't figure out, how to do it in QNX Momentics, since I do not have those options under the qcc Compiler.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can do this in the Compiler Tab of your QNX C/C++ Project as shown below:

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your answer! Though, do you know what could be the reason, why I do not see that option? https://imgur.com/a/aUBBiz7

Comment: Did you create a C/C++ project or a QNX C/C++ project? I think you can only see it if you created the latter.

Comment: Yes, I created a C/C++ project.
To be specific: New -> QNX Project -> QNX Executable

Comment: Yeah altough a slightly older version due to my used hardware. If the dev environment changed with the version I am unfortunately not able to help.